# ¿Cómo hago para que la variable ya no sea entera y me deje colocar texto?

Tags: python

Tengo el problema que creo que por la función `split()` no me deja colocar texto, es la primera vez que uso la función `split()` y no sé si lo estoy utilizando correctamente. Le coloqué `str` a la variable number en la condición `if` pero aún me sigue saliendo error ;( .

**Aquí el código:**

```
class FormulaError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super().__init__(msg)
```

```
number = True


def Calculadora():
    global number
    number = input(">>>")
    partes = number.split()
    entrada1 = float(partes.pop())
    signo = partes.pop()
    entrada2 = float(partes.pop())
    if signo != '-':
        suma = entrada1 + entrada2
        print(suma)

    elif signo != "+":
        resta = entrada1 - entrada2
        print(resta)
    return entrada1, entrada2, signo,


while True:
    try:
        salida = Calculadora()
        if str(number) == 'salir':
            break
    except FormulaError:
        print("Solo se permite el signo +")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. El código y los errores van como texto para que otros puedan leerlos correctamente y replicar tu problema. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: lo primero que debes hacer después del `input()` es preguntar si elegio `salir`, en cuyo caso **terminas**. Tal como está ahora, intentas procesar esa palabra como expresión y ,.. bueno ... no es una expresión.

Comment: [es.so] es un sitio de código y no de imágenes. Para publicar imágenes ya existen las redes antisociales como Instagram o Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres de una forma fácil lo que debes hacer es comparar el valor ingresado antes de hacer cualquier operación. Tu código quedaría así:

```py
def Calculadora():
    global number
    number = input(">>>")
    if number.lower() == salir: return number
    # resto del código
```

Sin embargo tu código está bastante mal escrito, ya que dificulta demasiado la integración de otras funcionalidad, como ya te habrás dado cuenta. Al escribir código siempre se trata de que esté ordenado, sea fácil de leer, debugear y mantener. Por esta última razón existen las funciones, que son pedazos de código encargados de ejecutar una tarea concreta. Por ejemplo, si deseas invertir una cadena podrías crear una función para ello, pero la función solo debe de encargarse de invertir la cadena, de nada más. La lectura de la cadena debe estar delegada por otra función. Esto para un proyecto simple puede no tener mucho sentido, pero ahora imagina que tu código va creciendo, ahora necesitas hacer distintas validaciones a la cadena para ver si cumple o no los requisitos. Si todo tu código lo tuvieras en una sola función esto sería tedioso, pero si lo tienes en distintas funciones solo debes escribir una nueva función e implementarla, así de fácil y sencillo (En la mayoría de situaciones de la vida real se lleva acabo los test antes que nada, pero en este caso no se necesitan).

A tu código le pasa lo mismo, tienes una función `Calculadora` que como su nombre lo dice, es una calculadora, la cual debe de encargarse de ejecutar las diversas **operaciones**. Como dije en un principio, la función debe de encargarse de hacer algo concreto, cosa que tu código no cumple, pues la función `Calculadora` aparte de hacer las operaciones también tiene como responsabilidad leer lo que ingresa el usuario y separar la cadena.

Resolvamos primero la lectura de la cadena. Esta tarea debería estar en otra parte que no sea la función `Calculadora` como tal. Para ello nos basta esto:

```py
def Calculadora(expresion:str)->float:
    num1, signo, num2 = expresion.split()
    num1, num2 = float(num1), float(num2)
    if signo == '+':
        resultado = num1 + num2
    elif signo == "-":
        resultado = num1 - num2

    return resultado

while True:
    try:
        cadena = input(">>> ")
        if cadena.lower() == 'salir':
            break
        Calculadora()
    except FormulaError:
        print("Solo se permite el signo +")
```

Pasemos a explicar lo que hace la función `Calculadora`. Esta función recibe una cadena como parámetro, luego utilizamos `.split()` para separar esa cadena. En un principio se espera que la cadena sea separada en 3 partes `num1, signo, num2`. El método `.split()` nos devuelve una lista. Sin embargo, en python hay algo llamado unpacking, que nos sirve para *desempacar* los elementos de un iterable, tales como las listas, tuplas o cualquier otro iterable. donde cada elemento del iterable será asignado a a la variable correspondiente definida al lado izquierdo de la asignación. Por ejemplo:

```py
saludo, nombre, fecha = ["Hola!", "Christian", "28/07/2022"]
```

Esto lo que hará será asignar `"Hola!"` a la variable `saludo`, `"Christian"` a `nombre` y `"28/07/2022"` a `fecha`. Esto es lo que se conoce como *unpacking* (también existen los operadores `*` y `**`)

Volviendo a la explicación de la función. La siguiente línea de la función `Calculadora` lo que hace es convertir los strings en float para poder operar con ellos. Lo demás ya te es conocido, un simple `if/elif`.

Sin embargo esta implementación aún tiene algunos errores, pues la función `Calculadora` se está encargando de separar la cadena. En principio puedes pensar que no hay de que preocuparse, pero puede darse el caso en que `.split()` devuelva más o menos elementos dependiendo de lo que ingrese el usuario, lo que provocará un error. Para ello crearemos otra función que se encargue de validar la cadena y si todo está bien pues se pasa a ejecutar la función `Calculadora` que sol hará la operación necesaria.

```py
def validar(expresion:str):
    partes = expresion.strip().split()
    if len(partes) != 3: return False
    elif not partes[1] in "+-*/": return False #ó raise FormulaError
    elif not (partes[0].isdigit() and partes[-1].isdigit()): return False
    return float(partes[0]), float(partes[-1]), partes[1]

def Calculadora(num1, num2, signo)->float:
    if signo == '+':
        resultado = num1 + num2
    elif signo == "-":
        resultado = num1 - num2

    return resultado

while True:
    try:
        cadena = input(">>> ")
        if cadena.lower() == 'salir':
            break
        cadena = validar(cadena)
        if cadena:
            Calculadora(cadena[0], cadena[1], cadena[2])
    except FormulaError:
        print("Solo se permite el signo +")
```

Con esto ya tendrías tu código estructurado de mejor forma, ya has separada la lógica del programa en distintas funciones y todo es fácil de testear e implementar nuevas funcionalidades. Si tienes alguna duda puedes hacérmela en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Te agradezco muchísimo tu ayuda y consejos, me encanto toda tu explicación tan detallada, la verdad que si me dejaste con muchas dudas y curiosidades no sabía que se podía colocar ":" como parámetro en una método en la universidad no me enseñaron ese detalle.

Comment: No es parámetro, los `:` se usan para decirle a tu editor de código que ahí se espera que el tipo de dato sea el que has especificado. Esto es solo una ayuda. Recordemos que python es de tipado dinámico, lo que quiere decir que las variables no tienen un tipo de dato definido. Lo que yo uso se llama `type hint` (si mal no recuerdo) puedes investigar un poco más para saber mejor como funciona

Comment:  ok eso haré y como sabías eso? es un tema especial en el lenguaje python o cómo?

Comment: Es una característica del lenguaje, creo que apareció a partir de la versión 3.5, así que te cuidado donde lo usas, ya que sino provocará un `SyntaxError`